# как работают вложенные функции?

Tags: python, функции, python-3.x

Здравствуйте.
Пытаюсь разобраться в работе вложенных функций в питоне. Накатал простую программку y = (x+1)^2, но она не работает. Почему?

```
import math
def stepen_x(arg):
   def summa_x(arg):
      result = x+1
      return result
   res = pow(summa_x(),2)
   return res
x = 2
x = stepen_x(x)
print (x)
```

Comment: Опечатка в вызове функции или в определение. У них разное название. И непонятно что должна делать вложенная функция.

Comment: Теперь функция `summa_x` принимает один аргумент, но никаких аргументов в неё не передаётся. И вообще-то про это всё должен был написать сам питон, такое в интернете обычно не спрашивают.

Comment: А что же вам пишет интерпретатор? Если есть трудности с пониманием английского языка (не исключаю такой возможности, имена функций как бы намекают), то гораздо проще воспользоваться онлайн-переводчиками, нежели ждать ответ на такой простой вопрос здесь. Удачи и не ленитесь!

Answer (score 2):

Если коротко, то вот решение:

```
import math

def stepen_x(arg):
   def summa_x(arg):
      return arg + 1
   return pow(summa_x(arg), 2)

x = 2
x = stepen_x(x)
print (x)
```

В чем была ошибка: нужно следить за тем, чтобы аргументы функции использовались в теле функции.

Answer (score 0):

В строке:

```
res = pow(summa_x(),2)
```

отсутствует аргумент.

Должно быть:

```
res = pow(summa_x(arg),2)
```

И еще, это не ошибка, но переменную `x` в операторе `result = x+1` функции `summa_x` нужно брать из аргумента этой функции, т.е `arg`, а не глобальную переменную `x`.